# filesink gstreamer does not work on android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, gstreamer

hi i am running this code:

```
      data->testvideo = gst_parse_launch("videotestsrc ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=25/1, width=640, height=360 ! x264enc ! \
                   mp4mux ! filesink location=test.mp4", &error);
      if (error) {
        gchar *message = g_strdup_printf("Unable to build pipeline: %s", error->message);
        g_clear_error (&error);
        set_ui_message(message, data);
        g_free (message);
        return NULL;
      }
```

but does not save the file in  data/data/com.mycom.videosave/files or nowhere.

And I have in my Manifest   (although I do not think this will affect)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Is it erroring out or just not doing anything?  Did you play the pipeline?

Comment: ok thanks for the advice to me missing the command

   gst_element_set_state (data-> testvideo, GST_STATE_READY);
   gst_element_set_state (data-> testvideo, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

just that my smart phone did not play the video but I think that's another problem

Comment: One thing to be aware of with the mp4 muxer is if you don't give it a clean shutdown it won't work properly--i.e. don't use whatever the Android equivalent of ctrl-c is and expect it to work.